# MySQL conditional select 1 of 2 fields, then group by a combination of the 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I'm a bit new to conditional statements in MySQL queries, I'm wondering if someone can help me out with the following?

I have the following table:

```
Company | Billing_State | Delivery_State | Revenue
```

How would I conditionally select the billing state if the company name equals 'XYZ' but otherwise select delivery state if not -- and then group by states, regardless of whether it's a billing state or delivery state? Let's say for the purpose of aggregating sales revenue reports by US states.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like:

```
select if(company = 'XYZ',billing_state,delivery_state), sum(revenue)
from companies
group by if(company = 'XYZ',billing_state,delivery_state)
```

Comment: Ah, so run the conditional IF twice. Didn't occur to me to do that. I'll give it a try.

Comment: yes. The if condition will be your result field and will be grouped by

Comment: $customers_query_raw = "select IF(o.customers_company = 'Acme Corp', o.delivery_state, o.customers_state), o.orders_id, o.orders_status, ot.value, ot.class, ot.orders_id, sum(ot.value) as ordersum from " . TABLE_ORDERS_TOTAL . " ot, " . TABLE_ORDERS . " o where ot.class != 'ot_total' and ot.class != 'ot_shipping' and o.orders_id = ot.orders_id and o.orders_status != '7' and o.customers_state != '' and o.customers_country = 'United States' group by IF(o.customers_company = 'Acme Corp', o.delivery_state, o.customers_state) order by ordersum DESC";

Comment: That's the actual query... and I'm getting a return of blank states in my list.

Comment: Nevermind. The subsequent php echo wasn't calling the proper thing.